# The pdf of $\{X_T\}$ where $X_t$ is a random process and $T$ is uniformly distributed

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

trying to understand a specific step of a proof and struggling.

$\{X_t\}$ is a gaussian WSS random process, $T \sim \mathcal{U}_{[0,1]}$ independent of $\{X_t\}$. 
 **prove/disprove** $$Y := X_T \quad  \text{is statistically independent of} \quad T$$
the proof starts out by saying $$f_{Y|T}(a|t) = f_{X_{t_0-t}|T}(a|t) = f_{X_{t_0}}(a)$$
and I don't understand the first equality here. where did the $t_0-t$ come from? I do understand that since $X_t$ is gaussian and WSS it's also stationary, and as such will be distributed identically regardless of time which explains the second equality but not the first. I understand the rest of the proof
$$f_{Y}(a) = \int_0^1 f_{Y|T}(a|t) dt= \int_0^1f_{X_{t_0}}(a) dt= f_{X_{t_0}}(a) \implies Y \sim X_{t_0}$$ for any arbitrary $t_0$ and thus is independent of $T$.